# Facebook Like button popup position

Tags: css, facebook

I have an issue regarding the popup position of facebook like button. When a user likes he will get a popup where he can type some text and confirm or decline the like. It's all perfectly clear.

Usually I put my like button plugin in the footer and I have no issue with that. User comes in, clicks like, popup appears, user scrolls a bit to see popup and all is well.

My problem arises from the fact I use parallax theme so when the user presses like page will increase its height to accommodate this popup and suddenly I can see the images from the parallax. This is ugly!

Please check the page [here](http://www.peonyapartment-sacic.hr) to see what I am talking about.

Is there a way to force this popup to open above the like button?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check it properly but why don't you try to make the position: relative where you put the fb like button and see your luck.